# Silverstripe 2.4 CheckboxSetField dbfield, save, get value

Tags: checkbox, return-value, silverstripe

Silverstripe 2.4

Whats the correct db-field to save a CheckboxSetField ?
How can i accsess the value from another page?

This doesnt work (ERROR [User Error]: Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'value' does not exist on 'Varchar'):

```
print_r(singleton('StartPage')->dbObject('Sperrtag')->Value());
```

And:

```
public static $db = array(

        'Sperrtag' => 'Varchar'

    );



$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Sperrtage", new CheckboxSetField('Sperrtag', 'Sperrtage', 
                array(  '1' => 'Montag', 
                        '2' => 'Dienstag', 
                        '3' => 'Mittwoch', 
                        '4' => 'Donnerstag', 
                        '5' => 'Freitag', 
                        '6' => 'Samstag',
                        '0' => 'Sonntag'
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Thanks.Till.

Answer (score 0):

you could do smth like this...

model:

```
"Sperrtag" => "Enum('Montag, Dienstag,Mittwoch,Donnerstag,Freitag,Samstag,Sonntag','Montag')"
```

field:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Main", new DropdownField("Sperrtag", "Sperrtag", singleton("StartPage")->dbObject("Sperrtag")->enumValues()));
```

or do you realy want to save multiple values?